# AJAX Like Call using signalr

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, signalr

I am trying to return the results of a search by using SignalR.  I would rather not use AJAX in this case as it will mean I have to build further controller methods etc, and as my application is largely built on SignalR I would prefer to use it exclusively.

My Hub Method returns some contacts, serialised as Json:

```
public string SearchContacts(string search) {

    return _serializer.Serialize(_db.Contacts_SearchContacts(search.Trim()).Select(o => new Contact(o.FullName,o.ContactId)).ToList());

}
```

My client method calls this method and deserialises the result:

```
function findMatches (q,contactsHub) {
    findMatches(q) {
        var matches = contactsHub.server.searchContacts(q);
        return JSON.parse(matches);
    };
}
```

The method call works ok, the server method runs, the client gets back results but the result string always comes back as "[object Object]".  I have checked the result on the server, and the serialised string is correct, so somehow it is getting lost/garbled on route back to the client.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out.  It can be done simply by working with the "done" function:

```
function findMatches (q,contactsHub) {
    findMatches(q) {
        contactsHub.server.searchContacts(q).done(function(result) {
            return JSON.parse(result);
        });
    };
}
```